# Проверка, является ли число простым

Tags: c

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");;
    int a, b;
    printf("Найти P!, если число является простым \n");;
    printf("Введите число a, больше 0 \n");;
    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    b = 2;
    while (b<a)
    {
        if (a % b == 0)
        {
            printf("Число не является простым \n");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            b++;
        }
        if (b = a - 1)
        {
            printf("Число простое \n");
            break;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Такая проблема. Нужно определить является ли число простым, и если да, то найти факториал. В данный момент я на пути написания кода для проверки на простое или нет. Вроде код работает, но возникает проблема с числами, которые заканчиваются на 9. Например 9, 39, 289 и т.п. Что не так, подскажите?

PS: Уже сам нашел ошибку. В "b = a - 1" нужно было поставить ==

```
b == a - 1
```

Comment: Вообще-то, достаточно один раз проверить, что число *нечетное*, а потом для проверки делимости без остатка перебирать *только нечетные делители*, пока делитель не больше корня квадратного из испытуемого числа

Comment: Ну да, как-то не додумался сразу. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Если вам в вашей задаче все равно придется находить факториал числа, т.е. принимать как данное связанные с этим проблемы (трудоемкость, опасность переполнения и т.п.), то это уже является заманчивым поводом применить [теорему Вильсона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Для числа `n` сразу начните именно с нахождения факториала `(n - 1)!`. Число `n` является простым тогда и только тогда, когда значение `(n - 1)! + 1` делится на `n`.

Если тест на простоту пройден, то вам остается лишь домножить уже найденный `(n - 1)!` на `n`, чтобы получить требуемый `n!`.

Comment: Не знал об этом. Спасибо!